# Terminate an ongoing QProcess that is running inside a QThread?

Tags: linux, multithreading, qt, qprocess

how to terminate an ongoing QProcess that is running inside a QThread and gets deleted by another QThread? I even inserted a QMutex extCmdProcessLock, which should avoid the destruction of the DbManager before the extCmdProcess could finish or timeout.
I get a segmentation fault on "waitForStarted" if another thread calls delete on DbManager.
I cannot use signals (I think) because I use the external command inside a sequential data process.
Thank you very much for any help!

```
DbManager::extCmd(){
    ...
    QMutexLocker locker(&extCmdProcessLock);
    extCmdProcess = new QProcess(this);
    QString argStr  += " --p1=1"
                    +  " --p2=3";
    extCmdProcess->start(cmd,argStr.split(QString(" ")));
    bool startedSuccessfully = extCmdProcess->waitForStarted();
    if (!startedSuccessfully) {
       extCmdProcess->close();
       extCmdProcess->kill();
       extCmdProcess->waitForFinished();
       delete extCmdProcess;
       extCmdProcess = NULL;
       return;
    }
    bool successfullyFinished = extCmdProcess->waitForFinished(-1);
    if (!successfullyFinished) {
       qDebug() << "finishing failed"; // Appendix C
       extCmdProcess->close();
       extCmdProcess->kill();
       extCmdProcess->waitForFinished(-1);
       delete extCmdProcess;
       extCmdProcess = NULL;
       return;
   }
   extCmdProcess->close();
   delete extCmdProcess;
   extCmdProcess = NULL;
}

DbManager::~DbManager(){
    qDebug() << "DB DbManager destructor called.";   
    QMutexLocker locker(&extCmdProcessLock);
    if (extCmdProcess!= NULL){
       this->extCmdProcess->kill(); // added after Appendix A
       this->extCmdProcess->waitForFinished();
    }
}
```

**Appendix A:** I also get the error "QProcess: Destroyed while process is still running." and I read that this could mean that the "delete dbmanager" call from my other thread is executed while the waitForStarted() command has not completed. But I really wonder why the kill() command in my destructor has not fixed this.

**Appendix B:** According to comment, added `waitForFinished()`. Sadly, the QProcess termination still does not get shutdown properly, the segmentation fault happens in `waitForStarted()` or as below in `start()` itself.

```
#0  0x00007f25e03a492a in QEventDispatcherUNIX::registerSocketNotifier () from /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.7.4/lib/libQtCore.so.4
#1  0x00007f25e0392d0b in QSocketNotifier::QSocketNotifier () from /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.7.4/lib/libQtCore.so.4
#2  0x00007f25e0350bf8 in ?? () from /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.7.4/lib/libQtCore.so.4
#3  0x00007f25e03513ef in ?? () from /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.7.4/lib/libQtCore.so.4
#4  0x00007f25e03115da in QProcess::start () from /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.7.4/lib/libQtCore.so.4
#5  0x0000000000428628 in DbManager::extCmd()
#6  0x000000000042ca06 in DbManager::storePos ()
#7  0x000000000044f51c in DeviceConnection::incomingData ()
#8  0x00000000004600fb in DeviceConnection::qt_metacall ()
#9  0x00007f25e0388782 in QObject::event () from /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.7.4/lib/libQtCore.so.4
#10 0x00007f25e0376e3f in QCoreApplicationPrivate::notify_helper () from /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.7.4/lib/libQtCore.so.4
#11 0x00007f25e0376e86 in QCoreApplication::notify () from /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.7.4/lib/libQtCore.so.4
#12 0x00007f25e0376ba4 in QCoreApplication::notifyInternal () from /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.7.4/lib/libQtCore.so.4
#13 0x00007f25e0377901 in QCoreApplicationPrivate::sendPostedEvents () from /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.7.4/lib/libQtCore.so.4
#14 0x00007f25e03a4500 in QEventDispatcherUNIX::processEvents () from /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.7.4/lib/libQtCore.so.4
#15 0x00007f25e0375e15 in QEventLoop::processEvents () from /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.7.4/lib/libQtCore.so.4
#16 0x00007f25e0376066 in QEventLoop::exec () from /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.7.4/lib/libQtCore.so.4
#17 0x00007f25e0277715 in QThread::exec () from /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.7.4/lib/libQtCore.so.4
#18 0x00007f25e027a596 in ?? () from /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.7.4/lib/libQtCore.so.4
#19 0x00007f25df9b43f7 in start_thread () from /lib/libpthread.so.0
#20 0x00007f25def89b4d in clone () from /lib/libc.so.6
#21 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

**Appendix C:** The debug output showed me, that the error message: *QProcess: Destroyed while process is still running.* always appears, when the *finishing failed* output appears. This means that my locks or/and kill attempts to protect the QProcess are failing.
Questions I wonder about:

a) If a create a QProcess object and start it, is my `extCmdProcessLock` unlocked? I already  tried to use a normal `lock()` call instead of the `QMutexLoader` but no luck.

b) The docs say the *main thread* will be stopped if I use QProcess this way. Do they really mean the *main thread* or the *thread in which QProcess is started*? I assumed second.

c) is QProcess not usable in multithreading environment? If two threads create a QProcess object and run it, do they interfere? Maybe the object is somehow static?

Thanks for any help in filling the knowledge leaks. I really hope to get that puzzle solved.

**Appendix D:** After removing any delete and deleteLater() from any thread, my QProcess still gets smashed.

```
#0  0x00007fc94e9796b0 in QProcess::setProcessState () from /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.7.4/lib/libQtCore.so.4
#1  0x00007fc94e97998b in QProcess::waitForStarted () from /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.7.4/lib/libQtCore.so.4
#2  0x00007fc94e979a12 in QProcess::waitForFinished () from /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.7.4/lib/libQtCore.so.4
#3  0x0000000000425681 in DbManager::extCmd()
#4  0x0000000000426fb6 in DbManager::storePos ()
#5  0x000000000044d51c in DeviceConnection::incomingData ()
#6  0x000000000045fb7b in DeviceConnection::qt_metacall ()
#7  0x00007fc94e9f4782 in QObject::event () from /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.7.4/lib/libQtCore.so.4
#8  0x00007fc94e9e2e3f in QCoreApplicationPrivate::notify_helper () from /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.7.4/lib/libQtCore.so.4
#9  0x00007fc94e9e2e86 in QCoreApplication::notify () from /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.7.4/lib/libQtCore.so.4
#10 0x00007fc94e9e2ba4 in QCoreApplication::notifyInternal () from /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.7.4/lib/libQtCore.so.4
#11 0x00007fc94e9e3901 in QCoreApplicationPrivate::sendPostedEvents () from /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.7.4/lib/libQtCore.so.4
#12 0x00007fc94ea10500 in QEventDispatcherUNIX::processEvents () from /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.7.4/lib/libQtCore.so.4
#13 0x00007fc94e9e1e15 in QEventLoop::processEvents () from /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.7.4/lib/libQtCore.so.4
#14 0x00007fc94e9e2066 in QEventLoop::exec () from /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.7.4/lib/libQtCore.so.4
#15 0x00007fc94e8e3715 in QThread::exec () from /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.7.4/lib/libQtCore.so.4
#16 0x00007fc94e8e6596 in ?? () from /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.7.4/lib/libQtCore.so.4
#17 0x00007fc94e0203f7 in start_thread () from /lib/libpthread.so.0
#18 0x00007fc94d5f5b4d in clone () from /lib/libc.so.6
#19 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

Comment: Tip: Instead of writing the arguments as one string and then splitting them, you could (should) write them directly as a QStringList like this: `QStringList() << "--p1=1" << "--p2=3"`. In your case it doesn't make a difference, but if the arguments come from user input, you get into trouble (wrong splitting of the arguments).

Comment: Nice code improvement tip, thank you.

Comment: Found out that the problem persists, even if I never ever delete any thread containing the QProcess object. Can QProcess's from different threads crash each other? The debugger shows a sementation fault inside the `waitForFinished()` function. Just like the QProcess object has accessed a pointer that got taken away from another QProcess. (Appendix D)

Comment: `waitForFinished()` returns before the process has finished.Somehow this is not blocking.

Comment: let me be a bit more precise about that last comment: If I use `this`as a QProcess constructor parameter, the `waitForFinsihed()` sometimes fails. 
If I use no parameter for the QProcess consturctor `waitForFinished()` returns before the process has finished.Somehow this is not blocking. I suppose because without giving the parent parameter the QProcess is running in the main event loop and the finished() signal does not reach it anymore.

Comment: Too bad that it fails with the status error: 5 what stays for `unknown error`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is really bad style to use a QThread to manage a running process. I'm seeing it again and again and it's some fundamental misunderstanding about how to write asynchronous applications properly. Processes are separate from your own application. QProcess provides a beautiful set of signals to notify you when it has successfully started, failed to start, and finished. Simply hook those signals to slots in an instance of a QObject-derived class of yours, and you'll be all set.

It's bad design if the number of threads in your application can exceed significantly the number of cores/hyperhtreads available on the platform, or if the number of threads is linked to some unrelated runtime factor like number of running subprocesses.

See my other [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10799130/what-is-the-reason-for-qprocess-error-status-5/10840448#10840448).

You can create QProcess on the heap, as a child of your monitoring QObject. You could connect QProcess's finished() signal to its own deleteLater() slot, so that it will automatically delete itself when it's done. The monitoring QObject should forcibly terminate any remaining running processes when it gets itself destroyed, say as a result of your application shutting down.

Further to the question was how to execute uncontrollably long running functions, say database queries for which there's no asynchronous API, with minimal impact, when interspersed with things for which there is good asynchronous API, such as QProcess.

A canonical way would be: do things synchronously where you must, asynchronously otherwise. You can stop the controlling object, and any running process, by invoking its `deleteLater()` slot -- either via a signal/slot connection, or using `QMetaObject::invokeMethod()` if you want to do it directly while safely crossing the thread boundary. This is the major benefit of using as few blocking calls as possible: you have some control over the processing and can stop it some of the time. With purely blocking implementation, there's no way to stop it short of using some flag variables and sprinkling your code with tests for it.

The `deleteLater()` will get processed any time the event loop can spin in the thread where a QObject lives. This means that it will get a chance between the database query calls -- any time when the process is running, in fact.

Untested code:

```
class Query : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  Query(QObject * parent = 0) : QObject(parent) {
    connect(process, SIGNAL(error(QProcess::ProcessError)), SLOT(error()));
    connect(process, SIGNAL(finished(int,QProcess::ExitStatus)), SLOT(finished(int,QProcess::ExitStatus)));
  }
  ~Query() { process.kill(); }
  void start() {
    QTimer::singleShot(0, this, SLOT(slot1()));
  }
protected slots:
  void slot1() {
    // do a database query
    process.start(....);
    next = &Query::slot2;
  }
protected:
  // slot2 and slot3 don't have to be slots
  void slot2() {
    if (result == Error) {...}
    else {...}
    // another database query
    process.start(...); // yet another process gets fired
    next = &Query::slot3;
  }
  void slot3() {
    if (result == Error) {...}
    deleteLater();
  }

protected slots:
  void error() {
    result = Error;
    (this->*next)();
  }
  void finished(int code, QProcess::ExitStatus status) {
    result = Finished;
    exitCode = code;
    exitStatus = status;
    (this->*next)();
  }
private:
  QProcess process; 
  enum { Error, Finished } result;
  int exitCode;
  QProcess::ExitStatus exitStatus;
  void (Query::* next)();
};
```

Personally, I'd check if the database that you're using has an asynchronous API. If it doesn't, but if the client library has available sources, then I'd do a minimal port to use Qt's networking stack to make it asynchronous. It would lower the overheads because you'd no more have one thread per database connection, and as you'd get closer to saturating the CPU, the overheads wouldn't rise: ordinarily, to saturate the CPU you'd need many, many threads, since they mostly idle. With asynchronous interface, the number of context switches would go down, since a thread would process one packet of data from the database, and could immediately process another packet from a different connection, without having to do a context switch: the execution stays within the event loop of that thread.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I appreciate it. I understand the bad design about "waiting" in a thread. If you would implement everything in a clean asynchronous way, please give me a hint how you solve such a situation: I have a thread that processes data and during this processing it needs information from a DB (query can last a few seconds) to do some operation on the data it stores at the end of its tasks back to the DB. During this data processing it needs to execute a shell command to get additional data to apply on the processed data.

Answer (score 1):

[QProcess::waitForStarted](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qprocess.html#waitForStarted) just signals that your process has started. The mutex in extCmd() method gets unlocked then because you are not waiting for [QProcess::waitForFinished](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qprocess.html#waitForFinished) in this method. You will **exit** this method while the child process is still running.

If you want to use a fire&forget type of execution I just you uses [QProcess::startDetached](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qprocess.html#startDetached)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I added waitForFinished, because I need the results to continue. (see Appendix B and edited code).

Comment: The process is still reported as "not finished" when its beeing deleted.