# What is the reason for QProcess error status 5?

Tags: multithreading, qt, qprocess

i have multiple threads running the following QProcess. Randomly they fail with error state 5.  The Qt docs do not give any more details. Has anyone a clue what that error could come from? Thank you very much.

```
extCmd = new QProcess(this);

QString cmd = "/usr/bin/php";
QStringList argStr;
argStr << "/bin/sleep" << "10"; // changed to ever working command
extCmd->start(cmd, args);
bool suc = extCmd->waitForFinished(-1);
if (!suc) {
   qDebug() << "finishing failed error=" 
            << extCmd.error() 
            << extCmd.errorString();
}
```

Gives me the output:

```
finishing failed error= 5 "Unknown error"
```

Comment: Error code 5 is the default error code, could it be that the process you are invoking is failing rather than QProcess?

Comment: whats in cmd and args?put that also

Comment: Hi, thank you for taking a look. I added command and parameter contents.

Comment: @cbamber85 good point to start: i changed the command to something that always works `/bin/sleep 10`. Now, I see that the parameter of `waitForFinished()` has no effect: -1 and 20000 always fails. How can this be?

Comment: Ups. I am sorry, I did a mistake in my log analysis, only a few percent fail.

Comment: @spikey It is still failing with `Error 5` or a different one now? And, out of curiosity, how many threads do you start simultaneously?

Comment: didn't process return with status code different than 0?

Comment: @cbamber85 it is still failing with error 5. I am running about 100 threads. Addtional note: I updated to Qt Libs 4.8.2 now, because I read about QProcess in the release changes, but the error stays. I get an addtional message: `QSocketNotifier: Internal error`. :-(

Comment: @KamilKlimek `extCmd.exitCode()` is 0 and `extCmd.state()` is 2 after the `waitForFinished(-1)` if `bool suc` is false.

Comment: 100 threads at once!  You should consider putting them into a `QThreadPool` and capping it at the number of cores - but I doubt this has anything to do with your problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tangential to your problem is the fact that you should *not* be starting a thread per each process. A QProcess emits a `finished(int code, QProcess::ExitStatus status)` signal when it's done. It will also emit `started()` and `error()` upon successful and unsuccessful startup, respectively. Connect all those three signals to a slot in a QObject, then start the process, and deal with the results in the slots. You won't need any extra threads.

If you get a `started()` signal, then you can be sure that the process's file name was correct, and the process was started. Whatever exit code you get from `finished(int)` is then indicative of what the process did, perhaps in response to potentially invalid arguments you might have passed to it. If you get a `error()` signal, the process has failed to start because you gave a wrong filename to `QProcess::start()`, or you don't have correct permissions.

You should not be writing synchronous code where things happen asynchronously. Synchronous code is code that blocks for a particular thing to happen, like calling `waitForCmdFinished`. I wish that there was a Qt configuration flag that disables all those leftover synchronous blocking APIs, just like there's a flag to disable/enable Qt 3 support APIs. The mere availability of those blocking APIs promotes horrible hacks like the code above. Those APIs should be disabled by default IMHO. Just as there should be a test for moving QThread and derived classes to another thread. It's also a sign of bad design in every example of publicly available code I could find, and I did a rather thorough search to convince myself I wasn't crazy or something.

The only reasonable use I recall for a `waitxxx` method in Qt is the wait for a QThread to finish. Even then, this should be only called from within the `~QThread`, so as to prevent the QThread from being destroyed with the tread still running.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I selected it as the answer to my question because there is no direct answer. I tried different approaches. First, avoiding _blocking_ (synchronous) code has become a must, for using QProcess in a multithreaded app. Second, I created one single thread that handled all requests by processing a queue, independently from the other threads.