# QProcess:execute blocks entire application

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread, qprocess

In my application I use the following code to create new threads and execute an external application in those threads:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
...
    WebSocketServer *server = new WebSocketServer();
    QObject::connect(server, &WebSocketServer::closed, &a, &QCoreApplication::quit);
    QObject::connect(server, SIGNAL(messageReceived(QJsonObject)), dm, SIGNAL(sendHandleProcessedFiles(QJsonObject)));
    QObject::connect(dm,SIGNAL(sendServerNotify(int, QByteArray)),server,SLOT( notifySender(int, QByteArray)));
}

void WebSocketServer::processTextMessage(QString message)
{
    QThread* workerThread = new QThread();
    Task *task = Task::createTask(Id);
    task->moveToThread(workerThread);

    QObject::connect(task, SIGNAL(workFinished()), workerThread, SLOT(quit()));
    QObject::connect(workerThread, SIGNAL(finished()), task, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    QObject::connect(workerThread, SIGNAL(finished()), workerThread, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    workerThread->start();
    task->execute();
}


void Task::execute()
{
    ...
    //Execute external program 
    QProcess process;
    process->start(cmd);
    process->waitForFinished(-1);
    //Execution should continue after termination of external program within the thread created in WebSocketServer::processTextMessage
    ...
}
```

Inside my task object I have to execute an external program, wait until its execution finishes and continue my program code. I want that my thread waits until the execution of the program terminates, so no asynchronous mechanism is necessary.

The problem I have is that not only the individual thread waits for the program, but the entire application is blocked until the program terminates. So all requests i receive for example for my websocket server are blocked.

I expected that the process is executed in the thread from where it's called and doesn't effect the other threads. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide the `Task::createTask` implementation.  Also, you don't specify exactly where/how `QProcess::execute` is invoked.  My suspicion is that `Task::createTask` is invoking `QProcess::execute` *before* the task is moved to the new `QThread`.  Just a guess though.

Comment: Please provide a complete minimal example, not snippets. All the code you show is correct, the missing bits are super-important since that's where the problem actually is.

Comment: Most likely you're starting the thread inside the worker object's constructor. Instead, you should defer it until the object is ready to use - i.e. you should fire it off the event loop, by using a zero-duration timer to execute an `init` slot/functor.

Comment: Finally, there's no point whatsoever to moving a `QProcess` instance to a different thread, unless you do some heavy computation/communication with the process. Most likely you simply want to be notified when the process is done: for that, you should *never* use a `waitFor` method; instead connect to the `finished` signal. Your code will run when it's time for it to run.

Comment: This question is most likely a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10777147/1329652). Seeing a `QProcess` and `QThread` in the same question usually smells bad.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I added some code hope it helps to describe the problem a bit better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand your question, your problem is here:

```
QThread* workerThread = new QThread();
Task *task = Task::createTask(Id);
task->moveToThread(workerThread);
...
workerThread->start();
task->execute();
```

Here, you're executing the task in the main thread not in that worker thread. Note that by [`moveToThread`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#moveToThread) all slots are executed in the new thread, not explicit method calls.

In your code, `task->execute();` is executed in the main thread.

Comment: I didn't know that. How can I execute it in the thread I created here?

Comment: @HansHupe A nice tutorial would be [this page](http://blog.debao.me/2013/08/how-to-use-qthread-in-the-right-way-part-1/).

Comment: Just make `Task::execute()` a slot and connect it to the thread's `started()` signal